# Regularity for the wave equation on the half line

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I would like to know the regularity of the wave equation under simple conditions.
Consider the wave equation on the half line:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-\triangle u = 0, \quad (x,t) \in (0, \infty]\times (0, \infty)\\ 
u(x, 0) = \phi(x), \quad x \in (0, \infty] \\
u_t(x, 0) = \psi(x), \quad x \in (0, \infty] \\
u(0, t) = 0, t\in(0, \infty)
\end{cases}
$$
where $u:(0, \infty]\times(0, \infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is unknown.
The PDE book by Evans says that the solution $u \notin C^2(\mathbb{R})$, unless $\phi''(0)=0$ [see Evans 2.4.1].
So, what is the regularity of the solution $u$ solving the above equation?

Also, I would like to know some references (books, papers, ...) since I am struggling with funding them.

Thanks you.

Comment: $u$ should be a function from $(0,\infty) \times \mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Please can you tell us where in the book Evan's makes such a claim

Comment: @JackT Thanks. I changed the domain of $u:(0, \infty]\times(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ since I deal with the half-line and the positive time. The claim is stated in the last sentence on page 69 (2nd edition, Chapter 2.4.1); "Note that our solution does not belong to $C^2$, unless $g''(0)=0$."