# Wave equation on the half-line: is there always a $C^2$ solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

This question has been asked again [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453956/regularity-for-the-wave-equation-on-the-half-line) but no answer was given.

The problem is the following:

\begin{align*}
&u_{tt}=u_{xx},  \ \ \  \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{in}\ \mathbb{R}_+ \times (0,\infty) \\
&u=g, \ u_t=h,  \ \ \ \ \text{on}\ \mathbb{R}_+ \times \{t=0\} \\
&u=0, \ \ \  \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{on}\ \{x=0\} \times (0,\infty)
\end{align*}
where $g,h$ are $C^2$ and satisfy $g(0)=h(0)=0$.

Does this problem always have a $C^2$ solution? If yes, is it unique?

In Evans's book (p. 69) he uses the method of reflection to construct a solution, which in order to be $C^2$, more assumptions are needed. This is that solution:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{2}(g(x+t)+g(x-t))+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}h(y)dy & \text{if } x \ge t \ge 0\\
        \frac{1}{2}(g(x+t)-g(t-x))+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-x+t}^{x+t}h(y)dy & \text{if } 0\le x \le t 
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Even if $h=0$, the solution above is not $C^2$, unless $g''(0)=0$.